# What to renew to change LOF/LOT links?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, tocstyle, etoc

Consider the MWE below. I use TIKZ-customization for nice link underlines. (using `renewcommand` for `ref`), which I for this MWE replace by `\textcolor{red}` (so textcolor is not the goal)

As you can see:

- The TOC has now a red pagenumber;
- The List of Tables (LOT) has **NOT a red pagenumber**;
- The link in the chapter is customized (red color).

The question now is: **what do I need to redefine to get a red pagenumber in LOF as well (and \textcolor is here a proxy, so I need to be able to replace my my TIKZ-replacement)?**

**See this MWE:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Test.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,final]{extbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=page]{hyperref}
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
{ \normalsize\addvspace{.5ex}\leavevmode}
{\llap{\etocnumber\hspace{0.75cm}}\etocname\hspace{10pt}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\hspace{10pt}%
 \makebox[-0cm][l]{\makebox[0pt]{\etocpage}}\par}
{}
\makeatother
\let\oldhyperlink=\hyperlink%
\renewcommand\hyperlink[2]{\textcolor{red}{\oldhyperlink{#1}{#2}}}%
\let\oldref=\ref
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\ref[1]{\textcolor{red}{\oldref{#1}}}}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{Test}
\hyperlink{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{Customized link}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ c }
 \hline
 cell1 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This link is not customized in LOT}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No answer has been posted, and I really want to know how I can customize the links in List of Tables/Figures.

Comment: Aren't there easier ways to underline links than this? Is there any particular reason you want to do it this way?

Comment: The reason it works with `etoc` for the contents is probably that `etoc` explicitly checks for `hyperref` and adapts accordingly. If you just use `\tableofcontents`, you won't get the customisation there either. If you compare what you get in the `.toc` and `.lot`/`.lof` files, you can see what ends up doing the right thing in the ToC case and use this as a starting point. I can't do this because I don't have the means to recreate the `.toc` since the relevant code is not included in your question.

Comment: Thanks cfr. In above MWE, I get the following `.lot`file. My question is, in this MWE example which code is responsble for producing the content of those `.lot` files, so I can customize it. `\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces This link is not customized in LOT}}{1}{table.0.1}`

Comment: @robert: Which parts of the element do you want to underline? Just the title, just the number, or both?

Comment: What you want to look at is the contents of the `.toc` for an example where the `.toc` links *are* customised. Then you can see what you are aiming to get into the `.lot`.

Comment: @Werner: I updated the openings post. I want to have a link under the table/figure number, the text and the page, the same as the `etoc`  table of contents with `linktoc=all`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imho there is no good way to change the hyperref commands. hyperref doesn't use a command with argument in this case. Probably the easiest is to redefine `\@dottedtocline`, e.g.

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     \tikzul[dotted]{#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

[image]

### Edit

as requested a full example with etoc, which changes the lot. `etoc` doesn't hook into the listoftables so one has to change again `\@dottedtocline`: The green and red color are placeholders for the tikz code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,final]{extbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hidelinks,linktoc=page]{hyperref}
\etocsetstyle{chapter}
{}
{ \normalsize\addvspace{.5ex}\leavevmode}
{\llap{\etocnumber\hspace{0.75cm}}\etocname\hspace{10pt}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\hspace{10pt}%
 \makebox[-0cm][l]{\makebox[0pt]{\etocpage}}\par}
{}
\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     \textcolor{green}{#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor \textcolor{red}{#5}}%
     \par}%
  \fi}


\makeatother
\let\oldhyperlink=\hyperlink%
\renewcommand\hyperlink[2]{\textcolor{red}{\oldhyperlink{#1}{#2}}}%
\let\oldref=\ref
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\ref[1]{\textcolor{red}{\oldref{#1}}}}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\chapter{Test}
\hyperlink{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{Customized link}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ c }
 \hline
 cell1 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This link is not customized in LOT}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, this is getting closer. However (1) it also underline the spaces between the tablenumber and the caption. That part is not clickable. (2) I am not sure it also underlines the page number probably not because (3) I cannot test because it is not working (with `pdflatex`) if I paste this in. I have updated my openingspost. How can I get something like this in style of `etoc+linktoc=all`

Comment: The number and the space *are* clickable. hyperref puts the link start before the whole argument (that means before the \numberline command). If you want to underline also the page number you will have to add your command around the `#5`. Btw: Imho this looks all quite bad, to many dots everywhere.  Beside this you should decide if you want to to use etoc or titletoc. Mixing both will give you only headache when trying to decide whose code is currently winning.

Comment: Thanks. If I use `linktoc=page` (less verbose link) and add customization to `#5` then this answer is the solution. HOWEVER, can you update your answer with the full *MWE*.  If I add your snippet to my (original) MWE, it does not work (based on `pdflatex`). Does your customization work also together with `etoc`?

Comment: Could please decide first if you want to use etoc or titletoc or none of both and where you want the customization? I really don't want to write lots of variants. Btw: You can replace all your tikzurl code with e.g. `\textcolor{red}`. This should be enough in a minimal example.

Comment: I updated my MWE in the first post. I used `titletoc` only for  `\titlerow`, so I replaced this by `titlesec`. Can you update your answer, and post a full MWE which shows this LOT in red?

Comment: I edited the code.

Comment: TOP. This is working now. Thanks for your help